# How to get the session/thread start time in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, multithreading, session, time

Is there any way to get session/thread created time in the MySQL Community Edition server with an enabled performance schema for a current(existing) session/thread?

Answer (score 0):

- Look for an "audit" plugin that would do what you want
- The "general log", if turned on, records the connect.  BUT...  It also records all other activity, so the file gets huge in a hurry.
- Write a Stored Procedure to record the time somewhere, then add this to `my.cnf`:

  ```
    init_config = CALL <<that SP>>
  ```

I think the SP approach has the best promise of meeting your requirements.  However, there is a caveat:  `init_connect` is ignored by "root" logins.  That is; it won't track them.  ("Root" should be limited to certain admin actions, not the general users or application connections.)